# Problems rendering a ceiling light with ARKit

Tags: arkit, 3d-modelling

I've been trying to render this model in ARKit: https://free3d.com/3d-model/traditional-ceiling-light-485.html. I have OBJ/MTL files for both the on and off version of the light. When I render them in Blender, they look like this:

[image: Blender rendering]

When I drop them into my ARKit test app, however, they look like this:

[image: ARKit rendering]

In Blender, you can clearly see that the "on" version of the light is kind of glowing whereas in ARKit both models look exactly the same. I'm guessing that the MTL file contains something that ARKit does not support. The MTL on the "on" version is as follows:

```
# 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 19.03.2018 16:33:20

newmtl Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Metal
    Ns 100.000000
    Ni 15.000000
    d 1.000000
    Tr 0.000000
    Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
    illum 2
    Ka 0.588000 0.588000 0.588000
    Kd 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    map_Ka Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Kd Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Ks Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Specular.png
    map_bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png
    bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png

newmtl Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Glass
    Ns 100.000000
    Ni 1.600000
    d 1.000000
    Tr 0.000000
    Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
    illum 2
    Ka 0.588000 0.588000 0.588000
    Kd 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    Ke 7.500000 7.500000 7.500000
    map_Ka Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Kd Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Ks Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Specular.png
    map_Ke Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Emissive.png
    map_bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png
    bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png

newmtl Traditional_Ceiling_Light
    Ns 100.000000
    Ni 1.600000
    d 1.000000
    Tr 0.000000
    Tf 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
    illum 2
    Ka 0.588000 0.588000 0.588000
    Kd 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
    Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    Ke 7.500000 7.500000 7.500000
    map_Ka Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Kd Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Diffuse.png
    map_Ks Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Specular.png
    map_Ke Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Emissive.png
    map_bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png
    bump Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Normal.png
```

Is it simply the case that ARKit can't render this model properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no light in your scene (or lighting environment) but it's hard to tell from your picture.

Make sure both assets have PBR materials and to get the best results, go through every single one of them. Pay close attention to the `emission` property, as obj files usually have them on white/clear grey. this is what will make the difference between the 2 objects. In fact, you only need to change the emissive property for 1 material to go from OFF to ON.

[image: physically based rendering materials]

Comment: How can I tell whether PBS materials are used? Is that something I can see in the MTL file and/or in Blender? In any case the models render fine in Blender. I can see that the "on" version of the light has a value for `Ke` in the MTL file whereas the "off" version just has zeros there. I guess this is the `emission` property you mentioned which is why I am wondering whether ARKit is simply not capable of displaying this model properly.

Comment: In terms of lighting I just set `autoenablesDefaultLighting` and `automaticallyUpdatesLighting` to `true` in my scene. Is that enough or do I have to set up a specific type of lighting to make the light glow?

Comment: You can chose the rendering mode yourself, whatever was used in Blender -  see the example above `Shading` is set to Physically based. This will override the MTL file (which you probably don't need). `autoenablesDefaultLighting` and `automaticallyUpdatesLighting` are both true by default so you can delete both lines.

Comment: It looks like your obj files were delivered with png textures, just assign those in the Scene Editor in Xcode. ie assign `Traditional_Ceiling_Light_Visual_Emissive.png` to the `emissive` - or just leave it black for the OFF lights.

Comment: So I guess what you're saying is that ARKit probably doesn't support all the information in the MTL file, but we can handcraft the models to have the desired appearance in ARKit. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, although all that 3D rendering is managed by SceneKit rather than ARKit.

Comment: OK thanks, I approved the answer. I'll probably need some help from a 3D modeling expert to get this right (I'm a developer not a 3D guy) but this puts us on the right track.